# Quickly make a font full of wildcard

Tags: fonts

I'd like to quickly make a font mapping any character to a wildcard but the space.

- I'd like to use it in a form input but can't make the input type to password.
- I don't want to modify the input's content because the input changes are listened by some components.

Do you know any tool or online generator for such a purpose?

Maybe you have another way than a font to achieve this goal?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, pick a character on https://icomoon.io/app/#/select or something and dowload the font as SVG.

Then edit the SVG to match any characters you want, and use online generator to get woff woff2 and any format you shall need.